# Deciding how to partition the system into microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

I was reading [microservice architecture](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html), about how to decompose an application into services. There are some strategies that can help, one of them is [decompose by business capability](https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-business-capability.html)

They put as the example of an online store, with these business capabilities: Product catalog management, inventory management, order management, delivery management, ...

I have one question here: Consider the same example, let's say that customers can order their products to our online store through two different web pages: webA and webB.

Which is a better approach, build two microservices (order-management-webA, order-management-webB) or just one with all the stuff (order-management)?

I think that both approaches have their pros and cons but, What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Where you choose to draw the line depends on your understanding of your business. 
If you are doing it for the first time (business and not microservices), you are bound to get it wrong. And you cannot just pick the lines which worked for similar biz as yours and use them, because like you said there will be pros and cons with each such approach.

Also you need to ensure separation of concerns in your service. One service should deal with one domain. Also it make sense to think from where you getting the requirements, if you have different biz teams, it would make sense to code req from those teams into different services (keep an open mind as there will be cross cutting concerns).

So to answer your question about the example, it depends on what exactly is OMS doing for each of these web pages? I can say one request might be coming from you web app and other from some marketplace where you have hosted a product(webB).

In that case, if order journey is different, it make sense to go for different services, if scale or qps of the two is different then you may have to design your oms accordingly or you would want to deploy them separately for their individual scaling needs.
If there is any other information that you have at hand or any perspective of biz that you have that makes you think that splitting them can help you, go for it.

But for cases where every thing is same and say oms keeps no information about the user they are selling to or products being ordered or how fulfilment going to happen (What i mean is that it keeps references, loose coupling) then you can make it work with one service.

Yes, there will be pros and cons with each one of them and you need to leverage one over the other and what suits you the best is best solution for you.

One more thing, and most important one, these services are small. you feel like you have done some thing wrong, or there is better way, you can always change it. Microservices should be small enough to change quickly and that flexibility is very important. 
And quite often this check ensures that you do not put more than what is really needed into a given servcie